# Swift get all KeyPath for a protocol

Tags: swift, swift4, swift4.1

In the latest version of Swift, is there any way to get all the vars defined by a protocol?  Imagine I have something like:

```swift
protocol Foo {
    var a: Double { get set }
    var b: Double { get set }
}

class SomeClass: Foo {
    var a: Double = 1
    var b: Double = 2
    var c: Int = 3
}
```

I want a way to take a `SomeClass` object and know to query against variables `a` and `b` because those are the two the protocol defines. For example, I may want to sum up the values of all the variables from the protocol.  e.g. something like this non-functional code.

```
let obj = SomeClass()
let paths = Foo.allKeyPaths
let total = paths.reduce(0) { $0 + obj[keyPath: $1] }
```

In my actual use case the protocol has around 20 variables. I don't want to hardcode an array of keys because somebody might add a new variable to the protocol but forget to update that array, for example.  I'm wanting it to be dynamic at runtime.

Comment: @zombie That will work for Objective-C protocols, since Objective-C is a fully dynamic language, but it will not work for native Swift protocols.

Comment: Is this possible with Swift now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible in the current version of Swift.